# Make a second API call and return data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need some help figuring out an issue.

I'm working on a web app and basically I make an API call which is an array of data to get someone's details and return them on the page, but for one param (editedBy) I get the person' id. So, I was asked to make another API call from where I can get that person's name.

```
import React from 'react';
import {getData} from '.api/calls';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {getEditedBy} from './api/calls';

const PersonDetails = ({userId}) => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [editedBy, setEditedBy] = useState('')

    const setDetails = user => {
        setFirstName(user.firstName);
        setLastName(user.lastName);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData(userId).then(res => {
            setDetails(res.data)
        });
        getEditedBy(userId).then(res => {
            setEditedBy(res.fullName)
        });
    }, [userId])

    return (
        <div>
            <p>First Name: {firstName}</p>
            <p>LastName: {lastName}</p>
            <p>Edited By: {editedBy}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default connect(
    state => ({
        userId: state.user.userId
    })
)(PersonDetails);
```

How can I return the person's full name and keep that value in place, instead of the id? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want, but if it's that you hVe queried an API and got an ID, and then need to query another API to exchange that for a name, then why not just put that second call in `getEditedBy`. Do the first call, `.then` the second call. That way your React component doesn't need to know more than one call is involved

Comment: Hello, thank you. I did what you suggested but how can I display the person's name instead of the id

Answer (score 0):

This should cover your case:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserDetailsAsync() {
        const userData = (await getData(userId)).data;

        const editedBy = (await getEditedBy(userData.editedBy)).data;

        setDetails(userData);
        setEditedBy(editedBy.fullName);
    }

    getUserDetailsAsync();
}, [userId]);
```

If you're not a fan of the `await` syntax for some reason you can go with the `.then` chaining but in any case you should make the second API call dependent on the first one.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData(userId).then(res => {
        const userData = res.data;
        
        getEditedBy(userData.editedBy).then(res => {
            const editedBy = res.data;

            setDetails(userData);
            setEditedBy(editedBy.fullName);
        });
    });
}, [userId]);
```

In your current solution, you're firing 2 requests simultaneously which will cause completely nondeterministic result for you. First of all, you're querying for the `fullName` not of the person who edited the post, but for the same person you just queried(if I understood your context correctly). Second, your state will be updated at different times due to the independent requests. Third - one of the requests may fail while the other succeed, thus leaving your component with  inconsistent state. Furthermore, you might have problems with trying to update an already unmounted component and you should have this in mind.